# Add custom classes to anchor in wp_nav_menu

Tags: theme-development, menus, themes, hooks, navigation

I want to add a custom class to anchors in `wp_nav_menu` outputs.

Default for example is:

```
<li id="menu-item" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom">
    <a href="http://example.com">example</a>
</li>
```

I want this :

```
<li id="menu-item" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom ">
    <a href="http://example.com" class="class">example</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can do this with the [`nav_menu_link_attributes`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/nav_menu_link_attributes) filter.

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'wpse156165_menu_add_class', 10, 3 );

function wpse156165_menu_add_class( $atts, $item, $args ) {
    $class = 'class'; // or something based on $item
    $atts['class'] = $class;
    return $atts;
}
```

Comment: How would I accommodate multiple different `atts` within the anchor? ie. not just adding classes but also adding `aria-expanded="false"`?

Comment: Like in the third line of the function.

Comment: I have a better solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/67859550/9207553

Answer (score 4):

I have solution to add class to anchor tag.

1: Step: add this in functions.php

```php
function add_additional_class_on_a($classes, $item, $args)
{
    if (isset($args->add_a_class)) {
        $classes['class'] = $args->add_a_class;
    }
    return $classes;
}

add_filter('nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_additional_class_on_a', 1, 3);
```

2: Then use it like this in your theme

```php
<?php
        // Show Menu here
        wp_nav_menu(array(
            'theme_location' => 'my-footer-menu',
            'menu_class'      => 'footer-top list-unstyled',
            'add_a_class'     => 'box-link text-dark',
        ));
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add classes natively via interface in admin. Open `Screen Options` (top right of the screen) and check `CSS Classes`. I don't remember if class applies to link itself, but you can always target link inside container with CSS (`.class a`).

Comment: Admin allows you to apply CSS only to <li> elements, not <a> elements as asker desires.

Comment: This does not add a class to the anchor tag, only the li containing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'wpse156165_menu_add_class', 10, 3 );

function wpse156165_menu_add_class( $classes, $item, $args ) {
    if(isset($args->add_link_class)) {
        $classes['class'] = $args->add_link_class;
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Now you can use `add_link_class` as an array in menus.