# Filter menu item <a> to add classes/attributes?

Tags: menus, filters

How can I filter the presentation of menu items to add classes to anchors?

I already have the code below, in which I leverage the per-item "Description" field set in WordPress admin's Menus creator. But it's a bit of a hack, and it doesn't leverage the "CSS Classes (optional)" field available in the Menus creator.

- Other methods I have seen filter to add classes to `<li>`. Instead, I want to add classes to `<a>` - but not to replace the classes WordPress itself already applies to `<a>`.
- I want to know how to take those classes from the Menus creator field "CSS Classes (optional)".
- But I would also like to hard-set the additional classes in code, not from the "CSS Classes (optional)" field.

  ```
    /**
     * ==============================================================================
     *                       INSERT CLASSES IN TO NAV ITEMS
     * ==============================================================================
     */

    /**
     * Store class names in menu description field.
     * Used, eg. to make a nav item hidden
     */

    /**
     * Descriptions on Header Menu
     * @author Bill Erickson
     * @link http://www.billerickson.net/code/add-description-to-wordpress-menu-items/
     *
     * @param string $item_output, HTML outputp for the menu item
     * @param object $item, menu item object
     * @param int $depth, depth in menu structure
     * @param object $args, arguments passed to wp_nav_menu()
     * @return string $item_output
     */

    // Use menu item description field to store class name for output to link
    function be_header_menu_desc( $item_output, $item, $depth, $args ) {

      // Only if menu is footermenu1
      if( 'footermenu1' == $args->theme_location && ! $depth && $item->description )
          $item_output = str_replace( '<a ', '<a ' . $item->description .' ', $item_output );

      return $item_output;
    }
    add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'be_header_menu_desc', 10, 4 );
  ```

**Update:**

This code seems relevant...

```
// via https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/241072/39300
  function menu_add_atts( $atts, $item, $args ) {
      $class = 'has-arrow waves-effect waves-dark nav-link'; // or something based on $item
      $atts['class'] = $class;
      return $atts;
  }
  add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'menu_add_atts', 10, 3 );
```

... however, that is imposes *only* the classes I specify (as opposed to any which WordPress also might). I would also like to extend it to add not just classes but also other attributes, eg. `aria-expanded="false"`.