# How to apply individual menu item's "CSS Classes" to <a>, not <li>?

Tags: menus, navigation

WordPress' Menu constructor allows you to apply custom "CSS Classes" to menu items...

[image]

However, those classes are applied to the list item which wraps anchors, and not to anchors themselves...

```
<li id="menu-item-320" class="btn btn-primary text-white menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-320 nav-item mx-3">
    <a href="#product" class="nav-link" aria-expanded="false">Product</a>
</li>
```

How can I ensure that the value I place in "CSS Classes" for a particular menu item (`btn btn-primary text-white`) are applied not to `<li>` but to `<a>` instead... ?

```
<li id="menu-item-320" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-320 nav-item mx-3">
    <a href="#product" class="nav-link btn btn-primary text-white" aria-expanded="false">Product</a>
</li>
```

FYI, I am using a [BS4Navwalker](https://github.com/dominicbusinaro/bs4navwalker).

Some related things I have previously tried...

- I am aware of a method to [add classes to **all** menu anchors](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/156165/add-custom-classes-to-anchor-in-wp-nav-menu/241072#comment456692_241072) - but I want to add classes to just one.
- I am aware of the possibility to [use ACF to add a custom field to the menu and output any value added](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-menu-items/) - but I would prefer that this can be by specifying the classes to be added in WordPress' own "CSS Classes", without ACF.

Comment: You gonna have to modify the walker or create a custom one for your needs.

Comment: @LuisRivera How do I access the value stored in "CSS Classes"?

Comment: Still confused about how to access the value stored in "CSS Classes". I have previously used the description field (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/308882/filter-menu-item-a-to-add-classes-attributes) but that isn't logical.

Comment: The latest version of this bs4navwalker for WordPress, which I was using, adds in this functionality - https://github.com/dupkey/bs4navwalker/blob/master/bs4navwalker.php Its answer seems to be around using the nav_menu_css_class filter.